# Haskell function composition - wrongly inferred type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, dot-operator

In the following Haskell code, the function typeError doesn't typecheck.

```
wrap x = [x]

listf :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
listf = id

typeCheck :: [a] -> [[a]]
typeCheck x = listf (wrap x)

typeError :: [a] -> [[a]]
typeError = wrap . listf
```

GHC produces this error if it's uncommented:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `[a0]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for typeError :: [a] -> [[a]] at tim.hs:10:1
Expected type: [a] -> [a]
  Actual type: [[a0]] -> [[a0]]
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `listf'
In the expression: wrap . listf
```

I don't understand why. `a` should be able to unify with `[a0]` - they are independent type variables. This is exactly the type it infers for for `typeCheck` - but not when the `.` operator is used.

Hugs produces a very similar, and similarly spurious, error message:

```
ERROR "repro.hs":10 - Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : typeError
*** Expected type : [a] -> [[a]]
*** Inferred type : [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
```

Furthermore, this works fine:

```
listf' :: [a] -> [a]
listf' = id

typeCheck' :: [a] -> [[a]]
typeCheck' = wrap . listf'
```

The problem only occurs with an [[a]] or [[[a]]] or greater. What's the deal here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have reversed the function composition here.

```
-- This
typeCheck :: [a] -> [[a]]
typeCheck x = listf (wrap x)

-- is the same as
typeCheck' :: [a] -> [[a]]
typeCheck' = listf . wrap

-- while this
typeError :: [a] -> [[a]]
typeError = wrap . listf

-- is the same as
typeError' :: [a] -> [[a]] 
typeError' x = wrap (listf x)
```

Now it should hopefully be obvious why this doesn't work. `listf` requires that its argument is `[[a]]`, but the signature of `typeError` claims that it works for any `[a]`.

Comment: Damn, that's what I get for trying to fix a bug in this code after years of not doing Haskell.. thanks.